# AngularJS mid-expression rounding

Tags: angularjs, math, rounding

Is there an easy way to do mid-rouding in a math expression?
e.g.:

```
{{(0.12 * x | number:0) * (2.4 * y |number:0)|number}}
```

Something like this, but this doesn't work.

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to do such a computation inside an interpolated template binding? I'd extract the computation out to a dedicated function and pass `x` and `y` into it to produce the desired formatted value. Testing would also be easier as you can assert on the inputs and outputs of just a function.

Answer (score 0):

From the Docs:

> If you want to run more complex JavaScript code, you should make it a controller method and call the method from your view.

```
{̶{̶(̶0̶.̶1̶2̶ ̶*̶ ̶x̶ ̶|̶ ̶n̶u̶m̶b̶e̶r̶:̶0̶)̶ ̶*̶ ̶(̶2̶.̶4̶ ̶*̶ ̶y̶ ̶|̶n̶u̶m̶b̶e̶r̶:̶0̶)̶|̶n̶u̶m̶b̶e̶r̶}̶}̶

{{  midRound(x,y) }}
```

JS

```
$scope.misRound = function(x,y) {
    return (0.12*x).toFixed(0) * (2.4*y).toFixed(0);
};
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)